# In unsorted data, I want to add values from a range of data to new cells based on smallest date in neighboring cells in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to add formula in column C which will fetch value from H2 against that cell of column C whose neighboring cell in column F has smallest date, and then from H3 and so on.

**Original Data**

[image: Original Data]

After fetching 1st 3 values from column H, following output is required. Based on these fetched values, dates have updated. Formula need to run for next 3 values in column H based on same criteria.

**Required output after fetching 1st 3 values from column H**

[image: Required output after fetching 1st 3 values from column H]

**Required output after fetching all values from column H**

[image: Required output after fetching all values from column H]

Maybe this might look like very basic question, but I have been stuck at making this work for a long time. Solution to this question will make my life a lot easier. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think that's not basic and I cannot imagine that you can solve this using formulas. You will need  some piece of code for that.

Comment: @FunThomas Is there a solution with formulas if I fetch only 1st 3 values? Any VBA solution to whole or partial query? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: PS it wasn't a basic question at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Office 365 you could make use of REDUCE:

```
=LET(b,B2:B4,
     d,D2:D4,
     n,2,
     r,ROWS(b),
REDUCE(EXPAND(0,r,,0),SEQUENCE(n),LAMBDA(x,y,x+SORTBY(INDEX(H:H,SEQUENCE(r,,2+(y-1)*r)),SORTBY(SEQUENCE(r),(x+b)/d)))))
```

`b` are the `on machine qty` values on column B.
`d` are the `production per day` values on column D.
`n` is the nth time you want the values of column H to be added/sorted to the calculation.
`r` is the number of rows of `b` (or `d`).

REDUCE starts off with `x` an array of all `0`s the same size as b.
Then the calculation adds the first 3 values of column H to `x`, which becomes the new array of `x`.
Depending on the number used for `n` the calculation will be repeated that number of times, changing the `x` values each time.
The end value of `x` will be the result of the formula.

If you want to add the individual values of column H to the smallest value of the 3 after each iteration, you could use this:

```
=LET(b,B2:B4,
     d,D2:D4,
     r,ROWS(b),
REDUCE(EXPAND(0,r,,0),H2:H7,LAMBDA(x,y,LET(v,(x+b)/d,x+IF(SEQUENCE(r)=XMATCH(MIN(v),v),y,0)))))
```

Here it looks for the first machine to match the minimum value of the previous calculation result + the `on machine qty` divided by the machine's daily capacity. The first found machine to equal that value gets the nth value of `H2:H7` added to it (refered to as `y` inside the REDUCE function).

Changing `H2:H7` to a smaller range will show the previous results. If you use `H2` you only get one value added; `H2:H3` are two iterations, `H2:H4` 3 iterations, etc.

Comment: Your formula works perfectly. 
Can this formula be modified in a manner that calculation adds only 1st value of column H to x, which becomes the new array of x, and then 2nd value of column H and so on. 
Issue I am facing is that if 1st value of column H was 500, adding that value to C4 still results in value in E4 smaller than other 2 values and 2nd value from column H is required to be added to smallest number.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by only the first value to x. It adds the first value of the first 3 values of H to the values of `x` in order of the size of the individual values of `x` including the values that are on the machine (B2:B4), just like you described in your question. If you change `n` to 1 you get your values after adding the 1st 3 values of H. Changing `n` to 2 adds the next 3 values of H to the previously calculated values, so it calculates the values of n being 1, followed by n being 2.

Comment: I meant that when n = 1, only 1st value from H (H2) is added in x instead of 1st 3 values. When n = 2, only 2nd value from H (H3) is added in x and so on till n = 6, when 6th value from H (H7) is added in x. I know this requirement is different from my original question as during application of this formula, I have run into exceptions.

Comment: Ok, this leaves me with a lot of extra questions, but really it's a different question. So it might be better to start a new question. Please make sure to explain how the first value of H is added to all 3 or only one of the values of B, because that's currently unclear to me.

Comment: 1st value of H is added to only one of the values of B, whose closing time (Days) is smallest. Remaining 2 values of B remain unchanged in 1st iteration (n = 1). When n = 2, 2nd value of H is added to that value of B, whose closing time (Days) is smallest. Remaining 2 values of B remain unchanged.

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to get to. I'll look at it some time later; no time now.

Comment: See edit in the bottom part of the answer for what I think you're after.

Comment: 2nd formula is precisely what I needed. Thank you very much for your patience with me and for your excellent solution to my problem. It means a lot to me.

Comment: Thanks, glad to help and I liked the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposal for a solution using `LAMBDA` (recursive) functions.
In the illustration, the input ranges (light green) are named:
`PPD` - `=$D$2:$D$4`
`Qty` - `=$G$2:$G$13`
`Start_Time` - `=$J$2:$J$4`

The `phase` parameter indicates the stage of the calculation: `0` – no `Qty` values were retrieved, `1` – the first 3 `Qty` values were retrieved, `2` – the next 3 values were retrieved from `Qty`.

[image: Plan]

`LAMBDA` functions are defined in the Name Manager:

`CT` :  `=LAMBDA(phase, IF(phase=0, Start_Time, CT(0)+NQ(phase)/PPD))`
`NQ` :  `=LAMBDA(phase, IF(phase=0, {0;0;0}, NQ(phase-1) +  XLOOKUP(CT(phase-1), SORT(CT(phase-1)),  CHOOSEROWS(Qty, {1;2;3}+3*(phase-1)))))`

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Your given solution also worked perfectly but solution from P.b is better fit for my working.